# SQL How to structure this particular db schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

I have two tables.

**User_types**

- (1)individual
- (2)business
- (3)student

**Relationship_cat**

- cat_id
- cat_name
- user_id
- user_type

First with `Relationship_cat`, i want an entry to look like this

```
cat_id(1), cat_name(interests) ,user_id(ANy user), user_type(only 1 and 3)
cat_id(2), cat_name(news) ,user_id(ANy user), user_type(only 2 and 3)
etc
```

With `user_type` i believe i could set it to 0 as default so it's not constrained to any user.  How do I go about the `"relationship_cat > user_type"` case?  Do I use a comma separated list of values? Is it efficient? And what if there are many `User_types` entries increase?

Comment: Where is the `cat` table?

Comment: short form for relationship_cat haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a many-to-many join table. So your schema might look like this:

user_types

- user_type_id
- user_type_value

categories

- cat_id
- cat_name

categories_to_user_types

- cat_id
- user_type_id

Any time you may think about using comma-separated values like you mentioned, this should be a sign to you to further normalize your tables.  What I have shown is typically the best way to express a many-to-many relationship between tables.

Comment: Thanks :) Does the categories_to_user_types need an AI and PK field?

Comment: Typically on a join table like that you would utilize a compound primary key across both fields.  You may also need individual indexes on each field if you are attempting to enforce foreign key constraints or if you may be utilizing those fields in individually in joins, sorts, filters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store multiple values in a single column, I would recommend introducing another table instead, to store those relationships as a one-to-many relationship.  Call it Relationship_cat_user_type and store the cat-Id and user_type_id values in that table.  This is best for normalization.

Good luck.